# Почему функция не возвращает значение?

Tags: python, функции

```
def srsumm(n,a=0,b=0):
    for i in n:
        a+=i
        b+=1
    return a, b
def printn(n,a,c=0):
    total, count = srsumm(n)
    c=total//count
    print(a)
    return c
def answer():
    a=printn(с)
    print(a)

answer()
```

Говорит, что не находит "с" (в printn(c)), но почему оно тогда нашло srsumm(n)?
И объясните пожалуйста, если было написано srsumm(n), как она возвращает a,b?

Comment: Функция answer() и в самом деле не содержит переменной c, которую вы куда-то передаете. Попробуйте почитать книги по Питону, в частности про область видимости.
PS. Тема вопроса тексту не соответствует...

Answer (score 5):

А откуда **c** в **answer():** должна появиться?  Я не программирую на питоне, но мне кажется, что вы в answer не передаете **c**